# jQuery Unexpected token in JSON for valid input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am getting the below error. I am not sure where I get the `'` symbol in the JSON. I have double checked and sure that the `json_encode` function of PHP does not add the ' symbol in the first position.

I have seen other question and solutions in StackOverflow and could not find any other solution in Google for this particular scenario.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at e.parseJSON (jquery-migrate.min.js:2)
    at fn (jquery.min.js:6)
    at k (jquery.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:6)
```

Below is the PHP code which generates the JSON string.

```
$info = Embed\Embed::create($videoUrl);

$result = array();

$result['title'] = $info->title;
$result['desciption'] = $info->description;
$result['type'] = $info->type;
$result['tags'] = $info->tags;
$result['provider'] = $info->providerName;

echo json_encode($result,true);
```

Below is the jQuery used to do a post action.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#videoUrl").blur(function (event) {

        if ($(this).val() != '') {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/url-here',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    "value": $(this).val()
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(errorThrown.message);
                }
            })
        }

    });

});
```

The sample response as found in the Chrome console is provided for your reference.

```
'{"title":"Inside of big gold mine in Africa. How it works. Documentary.","desciption":"Deepest mine in Africa.","type":"video","tags":["Megastructures","mine","gold","deepest mine","documentary","Deepest","how it works"],"provider":"YouTube"}
```

**EDIT:**

As requested I am sharing the entire php code.

```
public function getVideoDetails() {
   OW::getResponse()->clearHeaders();
   OW::getResponse()->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

   $videoUrl = $_POST['value'];

   $info = Embed\Embed::create($videoUrl);

   $result = array();

   $result['title'] = $info->title;
   $result['description'] = $info->description;
   $result['type'] = $info->type;
   $result['tags'] = $info->tags;
   //$result['image'] = $info->image;
   $result['provider'] = $info->providerName;

   echo json_encode($result, true);

   OW::getResponse() - > sendHeaders();
   exit;
}
```

Comment: remove the `'` in `'{"`

Comment: @guradio : If you don't mind can you point me which line? I could not find '{" text

Comment: `'{"title":"Inside o....`

Comment: In your sample response

Comment: @Purus You may have to share the rest of your code... the portion of the code you shared certainly shouldn't emit a single quote.

Comment: @BrettEast : The question is about removing the ' symbol from the response.. What's the point to remove it manually?

Comment: @smarx : All the codes related to this actions is provided. Please let me know if I am missing anything else.

Comment: I assume that somewhere there's code that is emitting a single quote. You haven't shared that portion of the code. How are we supposed to help?

Comment: add ' into end of the json like that "YouTube"}'

Comment: @hasan `Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0` means that there is an `'` at the beginning that is wrong. Adding one at the end will not solve the problem. The server already mistakenly sends the response with a leading `'`.

Comment: will you please post whole php file code

Comment: Hi all, 
The entire PHP code is provided.

Comment: You probably emit  an `'` at an earlier stage, by another `echo` or you maybe you have written `'<?php` in one of your php files.

Comment: Just try to return blank json and check whats its returning?

Comment: It seems likely that calling `sendHeaders` after an `echo` is a bug, but hard to be sure. I don't know how many times people are going to have to ask you to share the rest of your code... we'll get a couple more lines each time?

Comment: @t.niese : WOW.. You are such a genius :) You nailed it.. Silly one.. Thanks a ton. If you don't mind can you add this as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: closing sa typo then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common reason for unexpected leading characters in the response of PHP is that there is a character before the `<?php` in any of the included/involved php scripts.